# ASP.NET Core - 404 Not Found (No Routes Matched Location)

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an ASP.NET Core single page application using react.js. I am getting a 404 Not found when for POST within customer. I have tried using postman and passing through the appropriate data but having no luck finding the issue. I am not too experienced with this, if am I missing anything or you want to see more code let me know. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using KCA.Core.Exceptions;
using KCA.Core.Interfaces;
using KCA.Core.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace KCA.WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICustomerServices _customerServices;

        public CustomerController(ICustomerServices customerServices)
        {
            _customerServices = customerServices;
        }

        // GET: api/Customer
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> GetCustomers()
        {
            try
            {
                var customers = await _customerServices.GetAllAsync();
                return Ok(customers);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // GET: api/Customer/{id}
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> GetCustomer(Guid id)
        {
            try
            {
                var customer = await _customerServices.GetByIdAsync(id);
                return Ok(customer);
            }
            catch (NotFoundException ex)
            {
                return NotFound(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (BadRequestException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // POST: api/Customer
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> PostCustomer([FromBody] Customer customer)
        {
            try
            {
                await _customerServices.AddAsync(customer);
                return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetCustomer), new { id = customer.Id }, customer);
            }
            catch (BadRequestException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (ConflictException<Customer> ex)
            {
                return Conflict(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // PUT: api/Customer/{id}
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutCustomer(Guid id, [FromBody] Customer customer)
        {
            if (id != customer.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest("Customer ID mismatch.");
            }

            try
            {
                await _customerServices.UpdateAsync(customer);
                return NoContent();
            }
            catch (NotFoundException ex)
            {
                return NotFound(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (BadRequestException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // DELETE: api/Customer/{id}
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCustomer(Guid id)
        {
            try
            {
                await _customerServices.DeleteAsync(id);
                return NoContent();
            }
            catch (NotFoundException ex)
            {
                return NotFound(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (BadRequestException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `Program.cs` as I know there could be an issue within it

```
using KCA.Infrastructure;
using KCA.Core.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using KCA.Infrastructure.Data;
using KCA.Core.Interfaces;
using KCA.Core.Services;

namespace KCA.Web
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<KCAContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<Employee>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<KCAContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<Employee, KCAContext>();

            //Add Services
            services.AddScoped<IKCAContext, KCAContext>();
            services.AddScoped<ICarService, CarServices>();
            services.AddScoped<ICustomerServices, CustomerServices>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmployeeServices, EmployeeServices>();
            services.AddScoped<IPartsService, PartsService>();
            services.AddScoped<IJobServices, JobServices>();

            // Add CORS policy
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCors("AllowAll");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                     name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using Postman and passing through the appropriate data but still getting a 404 error

In Postman

```
POST https://localhost:44401//api/Customer
Body: (JSON)
```

```
{
    "Id": "b63da63d-5fd5-4b5f-8e33-4d4e7c9db927",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "ContactNumber": "555-123-4567",
    "Email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "Address": "123 Main St",
    "Postcode": "12345"
}
```

EDIT: this is the customer model encase it is something I am missing

```
using KCA.Core.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace KCA.Core.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Phone]
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }

        //Relational data
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want a different url then you your method name, you can do something like  [HttpPost("/api/Customer")], otherwise your url should be https://localhost:44401//api/PutCustomer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Hi Nonik, I have tried using the url you have posted using Postman but still getting a 404 back

Comment: You said you used the url `https://localhost:44401//api/Customer` - do you really have a double slash before api? Or is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: If you want a pure REST API you should be using `AddControllers()`, not `AddControllersWithViews()` and then `MapControllers()` at the end. Looks like you used a razor pages project template by mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

https://localhost:44401/api/Customer/PostCustomer

This should be the url with method POST and a body.

Comment: Hi Ahsan ,thanks for replying. I have tried this using PostMan with no difference

Comment: hmm... I see. Also, did you try removing the [FromBody]? I think this is not necessary when you are using the ApiController.

Answer (score 0):

In Program.cs file add services.AddControllers() after services.AddControllersWithViews()

Example:
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddControllers();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Api controller supports only attribute routing, no any ancient REST, or  remove ApiController attribute

so fix the routes

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
      ...
```

and  url

```
POST https://localhost:44401/api/Customer/PostCustomer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to post to http://localhost:44401/api/Customer/PostCustomer url. Problem could be https.